# How to upgrade PHP version of wordpress site in FTP?

Tags: php, wordpress, versioning

Could you please guide me how to change PHP version of wordpress site in FTP?
I can only access into FTP via WinSCP.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the `PHP` version of your hosting through the `FTP`. You can do it by accessing your `cPanel` or `Plesk` panel, if you do not have access to it I suggest you to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: It's in local server. not in CPanel such as Plesk. How do I access into it and upgrade PHP version and DB. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Maxim how did you install php in the first place? a wamp stack? or ?

Comment: @tim It's old site launched on intranet. I asked host and she doesn't know about it. It's hard to trace without permission to seeing server for me. It's a pain actually. I can go into wordpress admin panel and FTP folder.

Comment: @Maxim you need command line access or an admin system already set up that has that level of access, you cant do it via FTP or  wordpress admin. even with command line access you will need root permission.

Comment: @tim Thanks a lot, Tim. I will try to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify PHP version of your FTP directory by adding .htaccess directive:

```
<FilesMatch ".php">
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/phpXX-fpm/sockets/serwerXXXXX.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

it is working fine on lh.pl hosting.

phpXX is a version of PHP to configure and serwerXXXX is a server name.